# Return view and json data in one function

Tags: jquery, json, laravel, response, render

i would like to redern the view and send additional data via json. When I load data with ajax, I return the data directly and render the view.

Example code:

```
return view("archive.elements.category", compact('categorie', 'categoriemostvotedpost', 'categorieratio'))->render();
```

Questions:
How can I render the view and additionally send an error message as json in my jquery function?

example:

```
$data = [
                'message' => trans('messages.permission'),
            ];
            return response()->json($data, 401);
```

How can I send additional data to the jquery function as json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution

```
 $data = [
                'message' => trans('messages.archivechanged'),
                'html' => view("archive.elements.archiveposts", compact('posts', 'postscount', 'commentscount' ))->render()
            ];

            return response()->json($data, 200);
```